# SyntaxHighlighter with webpack and react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, syntaxhighlighter

I try to implement SyntaxHighlighter using react and webpack.

I install it via npm.

`npm install --save syntaxhighlighter`

It install perfectly. Now the problem is how to import it properly.

I've tried like this:

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'syntaxhighlighter';
```

But it doesn't work, Chrom console reports the error like:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

How can I use syntaxHighlighter with webpack and react?

Answer (score 3):

## Step 1: Install react-syntax-highlighter

```
npm install react-syntax-highlighter
```

## Step 2: Import react-syntax-highlighter

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
```

## Step 3: Import a style

```
import { aStyle } from "react-syntax-highlighter/styles/hljs-or-prism";
```

## Step 4: Display your code

```
<SyntaxHighlighter language="yourLanguage" style={aStyle}>
     {yourCode}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

## Example

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { docco } from "react-syntax-highlighter/styles/hljs";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={docco}>
                {console.log('Hello world!...');}
            </SyntaxHighlighter>
        </div>
    );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

## Live running example

- I created this live running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wyjp41m1zl

## Full documentation

- Supported languages for hls: https://github.com/conorhastings/react-syntax-highlighter/blob/master/AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES_HLJS.MD
- Supported languages for prism: https://github.com/conorhastings/react-syntax-highlighter/blob/master/AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES_PRISM.MD
- Github repo: https://github.com/conorhastings/react-syntax-highlighter